# Is there a difference between double quoting a variable or a whole line in echo

Tags: shell, quoting, echo

When you type, for example,

```
echo Variable "$var" is not initialised.
```

and

```
echo "Variable $var is not initialised."
```

the front end result is the exact same (as far as I know, at least). But I was wondering, from `echo`'s perspective, if there are any difference on how the command is ran.

And performance-wise, is the latter faster, since `echo` would recieve all arguments at once?

Comment: In this case no, not really, as far as the output is concerned. In the first case `echo` gets 5 args and in the second 1 arg. But `echo` concats its args on spaces - a single space per - and so it prints the same. Both uses are perfectly safe. You would see the difference if you did `echo "Variable  $var  is  not  initialised."` though.

Comment: @mikeserv, that's the answer, why don't you post the answer?

Comment: @mikeserv, with many `echo` implementations ([including `bash`'s under some circumstances](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/22565)), it's not _safe_ in that escape sequences in `$var` will be expanded. Generally, you want `printf` to print arbitrary data.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - very good point. I meant regarding `$var`'s expansion *as* an argument. But I wasn't even considering the possibility of backslash escapes in the expansion. Then again, if there are such, they will at least be preserved for `echo` to interpret. But yes, for a literal representation of *string* the most reliable method of getting such is as an explicitly declared `%s`tring argument to `printf`.

Comment: @glennjackman partly because it is incorrect - but also because a comment would suffice. Feel free to write it up better - I'd happily upvote it if you expanded on it.

Comment: As for performance, I ran a few loops. There was about a 10% difference. Nothing to be excited about.

Comment: @muru Ah! It's actually higher than I even expected, and it does actually answer part of my question; just to be sure, it was the latter that were faster, right?

Comment: @Linkyu yes, and I am rounding up to the nearest order-of-magnitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
echo Variable "$var" is not initialised.
```

You're passing 5 arguments to `echo` (6 if you count `echo`, the `argv[0]`), `echo` will output them separated by a space character terminated with a newline.

In:

```
echo "Variable $var is not initialised."
```

You're passing 1 argument (2 if you count `echo`).

In this particular case and in most cases, that is going to be functionally equivalent.

The second means less work for the shell to parse the command and store it into arguments before running `echo` and less work for `echo` to go through its arguments.

That's unlikely to make a very significant difference in terms of performance. In my tests, I see it making a small difference with some `echo`/`shell` combinations like `bash` with its builtin, but hardly any in others.

Other reasons why you may want to pass one argument instead of several:

- If you want more than a space between the arguments: `echo a  b` would output `a b`, you need `echo 'a  b'` to output `a  b`.
- In things like `echo "$opt" is an invalid option`, with some `echo` implementations like the `echo` builtin of `bash`, that wouldn't work with `opt=-e` (or `-E` or `-neE`...) while `echo "$opt is an invalid option"` would be OK.
- In `echo foo bar`, you're passing 2 arguments (beside the `echo` one) 3 byte long each, that is 2 pointers (8 byte each on 64bit systems) and 8 bytes including the `\0` string delimiters for the actual strings, so 24 bytes in total on 64bit systems.

  While it's one pointer and 8 bytes for `echo 'foo bar'` (16 bytes total). When calling the external `echo` executable with a large list of arguments, that can make you reach the limit on the size of the arguments sooner (though note that Linux also has a limit (128KiB) on the maximum size of a single argument).

In any case here, for arbitrary data (like that `$var` whose content we don't know (though from the context here we could derive that it contains only alnums and underscore)), you want to use `printf`, not `echo`:

```
printf >&2 '%s\n' "Variable $var is not initialised."
```

Or:

```
printf >&2 'Variable %s is not initialised.' "$var"
```

(here sent to stderr as that looks like it's meant to be an error to the user and not part of the normal output produced by your script).

And in that case, beside the format, it has to be one single argument passed to `printf`.

Another advantage of that approach is that it makes it possible to translate the messages in the user's language where you can provide ready made translations of that `Variable %s is not initialised.` format in all supported languages (and using `gettext` or ksh93/bash's `$"..."` to retrieve them).

Comment: One year and a half since I've posted this, but definitely worth the wait. Splendid answer!